RDP to Ubuntu from windows
We have an ubuntu server running at home, with two users. We have a Win laptop and I can RDP into the Ubuntu but when starting Blender it starts but does not display it. After some digging I found that it might be because of the OpenGL. I tried VNC that works, but I can not log in simultaneously using the ubuntu with an other user too, like I can with RDP.I only can "take over" the desktop!
Is there a solution to run the Blender remotely (local network only) from Windows utilizing the user's login?
